# 'go install' trying to install to /usr/lib/go instead of my GOPATH. Permission denied

Tags: go

I have had some difficulties getting Go up and running correctly on Linux Mint 14.  I have a folder ($HOME/develop/gocode) with `bin`, `pkg` and `src` folders as my `GOPATH` and have the `GOPATH` environment variable set properly there.  I tried installing a certain github repository using `go get` (https://github.com/jbarham/primegen.go) but Go gave me the error: `stat github.com/jbarham/primegen.go: no such file or directory` (I think because the repository ends in .go.)  Fine, I just cloned it manually, but then when I try to `go install` one of two executables in that repository (neither one works, but I tried installing primespeed first) I get the following error:

```
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/jbarham/primegen.go/primespeed
$ go install
go install github.com/jbarham/primegen.go: mkdir /usr/lib/go/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com: permission denied
```

Why is go trying to install the package there?  I've explicitly set my `GOPATH` variable, and yet it is trying to install packages to /usr/local instead.

I'm not sure if it will help, but here is some other output regarding version and environment:

```
$ go env
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOBIN=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOCHAR="6"
GOOS="linux"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
$ go version
go version go1.0.2
```

Comment: Something is fishy -- why isn't `GOPATH` showing up in your `go env` output?

Comment: Did you "export GOPATH"?

Answer (score 8):

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go

export GOBIN=$HOME/go/bin
```

try it.

Answer (score 5):

1. Your GOPATH is probably not exported.
2. Yes, repositories having a `.go` extension are not 'go gettable'.

Ad 1. (better put into .bashrc or equivalent):

```
$ export GOPATH=$HOME # just an example
```

Ad 2. (better raise an [issue](https://github.com/jbarham/primegen.go/issues/new) about the nonsensical repository name):

```
$ mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/jbarham
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/jbarham
$ git clone https://github.com/jbarham/primegen.go.git
$ cd primegen.go
$ go install
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case.  I definitely have GOPATH exported and can `go install` other packages just fine.  I just assume that the '.go' at the end of the package is what is causing the errors.  Maybe some other day I'll learn more about what's going on behind the scenes and figure out the culprit and submit a patch for it.  As for now, I've moved on to other projects to satisfy my Go curiosity.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's weird, when I do a `go env` the `GOPATH` is listed. I can't see it in your output above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but found that, the for some repos you need to specifically add the export `GOPATH`. for example from my `GOPATH`

```
cd $GOPATH
export GOPATH=$PWD && go get -d github.com/nsf/gocode
```

you could avoid it all together I guess, if you alias it:

```
alias goget='cd $GOPATH; export GOPATH=$PWD && go get'
```

This isn't perfect and oddly enough `export GOPATH=$GOPATH` does not work.
for some reason some repos are resetting the `GOPATH` to `$HOME` and trying to execute as a different user. 
My guess is some development code somewhere in the `go get` method that is messing with the calls. [just a hunch, don't quote me]